# How to exclude inner tags with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hey Im currently trying to parse through a website and I'm almost done, but there's a little problem. I wannt to exclude inner tags from a html code

```js
<span class="moto-color5_5">
  <strong>Text 1 </strong>
  <span style="font-size:8px;">Text 2</span>
</span>
```

I tried using 
...`find("span", "moto-color5_5")` but this returns

Text 1 Text 2 
instead of only returning Text 1

Any suggestions?

sincierly :)

Comment: Try using Regex

Comment: isnt there a way to do this with regular beautifulsoup operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding inner tags would also exclude `Text 1` because it's in an inner tag `<strong>`.

You can however just find `strong` inside of your current soup:

```
html = """<span class="moto-color5_5">
  <strong>Text 1 </strong>
  <span style="font-size:8px;">Text 2</span>
</span>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
result = soup.find("span", "moto-color5_5").find('strong')
print(result.text) # Text 1
```

Comment: what if the html would look like this:

<span class="moto-color5_5">
  Text 1 
  <span style="font-size:8px;">Text 2</span>
</span>

how could i exclude text 1 now?